# How to catch when user close a console application via “X” button

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-7-x64

I have to write data in memory to in a file to close my console application. How can i detect console closing event ?

Comment: Ever get an answer to this by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

When the terminal is closed, your program will get a SIGHUP, which kill it by default. add a signal handler to handle the SIGHUP do whatever you want. and if you program write to the console after it has been close, you may also get SIGPIPE, handle it properly

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html?highlight=sighup#signal.signal), "On Windows, `signal()` can only be called with `SIGABRT`, `SIGFPE`, `SIGILL`, `SIGINT`, `SIGSEGV`, or `SIGTERM`. A `ValueError` will be raised in any other case." Which means it isn't possible to set up a signal handler for `SIGHUP` on that platform, at least from Python.

Comment: In fact, on Windows, `signal.SIGHUP` isn't even defined.

Comment: Sorry didn't see that is windows